# SharePoint 2007 Auto Complete On A Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

The scenario is when you have 100+ items under your drop down menu its such a pain too look for it. The solution is have it like Google auto-complete. By clicking the drop down menua and your searching for "Pop" all the words with "Pop" will be sorted out and instead of 100+ you now  have 3. Pop, Pop-Rock and K-Pop.

Is that possible using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. I would recommend doing this along with JQUERY. You can find a good sample here:

- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
- http://asphive.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/autocomplete-on-sharepoint-dropdownlist-column/
- http://www.binaryjam.com/2010/12/06/jquery-autocomplete-for-sharepoint-search-box/